# Найти определенный отрывок заключить его в тег span

Tags: javascript, css

Мне нужно выделить отрывок текста с помощью javascript.
Как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: за что закрытие

Comment: А где ваша попытка решить эту задачу? Где код?

Comment: а обязательно нужна попытка. если я не знаю.

Comment: Зайдите в меню закрытия вопросов и почитайте формулировки.

Comment: Может вместо оборачивания в span что-то [из этого](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/) поиспользовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str_text = 'вопрос',
    obj_elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
    
var RegExp = new RegExp(str_text, 'g');
    
obj_elem.innerHTML = obj_elem.innerHTML.replace( RegExp, '<span class="select">' + str_text + '</span>' );
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.color {
  color: #00a1ff;
}

.select {
  background-color: yellow; 
  color: black; 
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<span id="elem"><b>Ответить на собственный вопрос</b> - <span class="color">делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и ответов</span>.</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgvEdv

```
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum — название классического текста-«рыбы». «Рыба» — слово из жаргона дизайнеров, обозначает условный, зачастую бессмысленный текст, вставляемый в макет страницы. Lorem ipsum представляет собой искажённый отрывок из философского трактата Цицерона «О пределах добра и зла», написанного в 45 году до нашей эры на латинском языке. Впервые этот текст был применен для набора шрифтовых образцов неизвестным печатником в XVI веке.
</div>
<p><a href="#" onclick="clear(); findText()">Найти строку</a></p>


var textOriginal = "", textDiv = null;

function findText(){
    var string = prompt("Введите символ для поиска", ""), text = "";

    if(string === undefined || string === null || string === "") return;

    var arr = textOriginal.split(string), i = 0, len = arr.length - 1;

    for(; i < len; i++){
        text += arr[i];
        text += "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>" + string + "</span>";
    }

    text += arr[i];
    textDiv.innerHTML = text; 
}

function clear() {
    textDiv.innerHTML = textOriginal;
}

window.onload = function() {
    textDiv = document.getElementById("text");
    textOriginal = textDiv.innerHTML;
}
```