# Выделить найденную подстроку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выделить найденную подстроку. Есть текст, я ввожу в поле значение, которое хочу найти и нужно найденные совпадения выделить жирным, что, собственно не получается. Я в этом деле новичок, вот пример кода

```html
<input type="text" name="find" id="find" value="" onchange="show()">
<button type="button" onclick="show()">Нажать</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="text" style="width:400px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne pro exerci suavitate. Ea amet appareat adversarium mei. Ei suscipit salutandi molestiae cum, eam te feugiat eruditi quaerendum. Denique indoctum urbanitas ne nec, ius putent aliquid laoreet ad, admodum hendrerit qui ut. Pro labore luptatum ad. Et cum nonumy adolescens, te harum salutatus vis. Semper delicatissimi ei mea.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function show () {
    var word = document.getElementById("find").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    var i = 0;
    do {
      var x = text.indexOf(word, i);
      i = x + 1;
      alert (x) // вывел чтобы смотреть результат

    } while (x != -1)

  }

</script>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Возможно подойдёт решение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686311/227016) вопроса

Comment: я пытался реплейсом уже делать, но нет эффекта. Ну для подлинности эксперимента еще раз попробовал сделал вот так 
var res = 0;
res.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace (word, '<b>' + word + '</b>');
и вот так 
text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace (word, '<b>' + word + '</b>')
и return делал эту переменную... я что-то делаю не так и не могу разобраться что именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var oldText = null;

function show() {
  var word = document.getElementById("find").value;
  var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

  if (!oldText)
    oldText = text;

  var newText;

  if (false) { // using String.split/Array.join
    var parts = oldText.split(word);
    console.log("count = " + (parts.length - 1));
    newText = parts.join("<b>" + word + "</b>");
  } else { // using String.replace
    newText = oldText.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"), "<b>" + word + "</b>");
  }

  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = newText;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="find" id="find" value="" onchange="show()">
<button type="button" onclick="show()">Нажать</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="text" style="width:400px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne pro exerci suavitate. Ea amet appareat adversarium mei. Ei suscipit salutandi molestiae cum, eam te feugiat eruditi quaerendum. Denique indoctum urbanitas ne nec, ius putent aliquid laoreet ad, admodum hendrerit qui ut.
  Pro labore luptatum ad. Et cum nonumy adolescens, te harum salutatus vis. Semper delicatissimi ei mea.
</div>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, ваша функция работает, но мне все же хотелось бы дополнить мои наработки

Comment: @Ярослав добавил вариант с `String.replace`